# How to create a pandas dataframe from a json file with multiple arrays

Tags: ios, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I’m trying to create a pandas dataframe from a json file that I have of my Apple Health Data.

My json file looks like this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "workouts": [],
    "metrics": [
      {
        "name": "active_energy",
        "units": "kcal",
        "data": [
          {
            "qty": 213.881,
            "date": "2022-04-12 00:00:00 -0600"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "apple_exercise_time",
        "units": "min",
        "data": [
          {
            "date": "2022-04-12 00:00:00 -0600",
            "qty": 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "sleep_analysis",
        "units": "min",
        "data": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In this data, there is an empty array called `workouts` and another called `metrics`. I want to take the `metrics` array from this file and turn it into a pandas dataframe like this:

| date | name | qty | units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-12 | active_energy | 213.881 | kcal |
| 2022-04-12 | apple_excersise_time | 6 | min |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using a DataFrame constructor, `explode` and `join`:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(my_data['data']['metrics']).explode('data')
s = tmp['data'].dropna()
out = tmp.drop(columns='data').join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index))
```

Output:

```
                  name units      qty                       date
0        active_energy  kcal  213.881  2022-04-12 00:00:00 -0600
1  apple_exercise_time   min    6.000  2022-04-12 00:00:00 -0600
2       sleep_analysis   min      NaN                        NaN
```

Comment: This almost worked! I got an error message (e.g., AttributeError : ‘float’ error has no object ‘keys’) when running your second line, though.

Comment: @Jake there's probably NaN values in the DataFrame. Check `tmp.isna().sum()`

Comment: Yes, there are. I didn’t include all of my data in the example I provided, but some of the values for qty have NaN values. Any suggestions on how to manage this with these NaN values?

Comment: I updated my question to include a record in the JSON that includes one of these NaN examples.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on SO shared this with me around a month ago. Sharing with you now.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("https://www.chsli.org/sites/default/files/transparency/111888924_GoodSamaritanHospitalMedicalCenter_standardcharges.json", lines=True)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv(r'C:\\your_path_here\\chsli.csv')
```

Result:

[image]